# How to add tooltip on an Image in Canvas in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

I am trying to add a tooltip on images inside a canvas in react js.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById(`myCanvas`);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = image.jpg;
backgroundImage.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
  if (marker_details.length > 0) {
    marker_details.forEach((marker) => {
      const markerImage = new Image();
      markerImage.title = marker.notes;
      const markerSize = 17;
      markerImage.src = markerImage.jpg;
      ctx.drawImage(markerImage, marker.coordinate_x, marker.coordinate_y, markerSize, markerSize);
    });
  }
};
```

`Image.title` doesn't work. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: you should avoid make use of `getElementBy***` methods so far you are using react. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Of course it *doesn't work*, real question why do you even expect html title to work in this case. You need to do it differently.

Comment: I think you have to make workaround like that https://jsfiddle.net/fb5qnftk/90/